# amazon lambda timezome mysql java issue

Tags: java, mysql, aws-lambda

So I'm learning Amazon Lambda seeing if I can make Alexa (Amazon Echo) communicate with a MySQL backend.  I setup an Amazon RDS that's public facing and set up a simple java handler that sets up a jdbc connection via the DriverManager.

Using the Java library for mysql, I used the DriveManager#getConnection method to create a connection.  Locally, this works, and my query returns what I expect it to.  However, when I upload the handler to the Amazon Lambda console and test it, I get the following cause for the error:

```
"cause": {
  "errorMessage": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
  "errorType": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
  "stackTrace": [
    "java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)",
    "java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)",
    "java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)",
    "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.util.TimeUtil.loadTimeZoneMappings(TimeUtil.java:163)",
    "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.util.TimeUtil.getCanonicalTimezone(TimeUtil.java:109)",
...
```

I did some googling on this and found https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79343.  It seems that a properties file needs to be defined on the server that's running the code.  My question is whether anyone else has tried to connect to a mysql server using JDBC via Amazon Lambda, or if everyone just used NodeJS or Python and not java.  If so, did anyone figure out a workaround for this or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Just a little direction here.   I have not used this, but have had similar issues using the Java 8 lambda.  Try adding a property file to the root of your zip file that is needed by the JDBC utility.  This is of course assuming that you found out what that properties file looks like.  Remember, the lambda really does not have much loaded and just like 3rd party jar files, you need to supply everything.

Comment: So, I found a workaround.  I added "?&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC" to my jdbc url, and I get the results I expected.  It's just silly that I'd have to do that.

To your point Chewy, I did take a look and the properties file is in the jar files that's included in my package, and it looks like the paths are just different.  My jar's path is "com/mysql/cj/jdbc/util/TimeZoneMapping.properties".  I don't know where the "cj" came from, but I'm betting that's what's causing issues.  Thanks for pointing me in that direction, though.